# Testing nodejs gRPC client functions

Tags: nodejs, jestjs

I have a task to test gRPC client call functions with Jest. Here is what a whole thing looks like:

We import a package from proto file:

```
const packageDef = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH,{
    keepCase: true,
    longs: String,
    enums: String,
    defaults: true,
    oneofs: true
}
```

);

And then we register client:

```
const loadPackageDef = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDef).dmz_api;
const client = new loadPackageDef.Authentication('localhost:3030', grpc.credentials.createInsecure());
```

**and here is the function I need to test:**

```
client.authenticate(request, meta, (error, response) => {
    if (!error) {
        console.log('REPLY FROM SERVER: ', response)
    } else {
        console.error(error)
    }
})
```

Procedure calls are callback functions, as we see I can not export response object to outside variable. I need to check if the function has been called with no error.

How do I do it with jest? Note that it's end-to-end testing and I *can not and should not* mock anything.Been struggling for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no sync alternative i could find for that method, so you could validate everything inside the callback itself or wrap it with a promise:

```
  let authenticateSync =    function (request, meta) {

  return new Promise(  (resolve, reject) => {  
  client.authenticate(request, meta, (error, response) => {
      if (!error) {
          resolve('REPLY FROM SERVER: ', response)
      } else {
          reject(error)
      }
   })
  })
},

let output = await authenticateSync(request, meta);
```